# Why apply resolutons in data words for ARINC 429 bus

Tags: cockpit, datasets, arinc-429

Data words transported over the ARINC 429 bus are defined and built-in units, ranges, refresh rates, number of significant bits, and resolution.

Why is it necessary to include resolution? Does resolution really have any significant impact on the signal? I think resolution is just a mere step size for the signal, so why use incremental resolutions, like 0.0000000002? Does this small incremental really make a difference in the data word?

Comment: Not sure if i understand your question correctly. Do you ask why it is necessary to define a resolution? If you have a limited number of bits which have to encode certain range of data, you will have a limited resolution.

Comment: The resolution tells you what value to assign to your LSB of the received value

Comment: @selectstriker2 why is that important?  How does that impact the signal?

Comment: It doesn't affect the signal, it helps decode the data in the 32 bit word

Comment: @selectstriker2 Thanks -- you last 2 comments are helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ARINC 429 Word resolution tells you what value the LSB corresponds to. You can also tell what the resolution should be by looking at the Range and Significant Bits.

It doesn't describe the actual electrical signal.